# Alternative BigQuery Writer to the plugin provided by google?

Tags: java, groovy, google-bigquery

Recently I upgraded my system to java 8. I am using Groovy. I have data that I need to write to Big Query.

In short: the data gets extracted from my database, gets pushed into a queue (RabbitMQ) and when it comes out of the queue, the data is formatted for Big Query and is sent to be added to the Big Query Table.

I am stuck at the first step: Installing a BigQuery plug in so that I can connect to my table and then push data to my table after formatting the data.

I tried adding the recommended Big Query plug in, from google but I get the following error:

```
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:zip:26.3.0 from/to repo_grails_org_ui_native_plugins_org_grails_plugins (https://repo.grails.org/ui/native/plugins/org/grails/plugins): Checksum validation failed, expected <!doctype but is 1b29c3f550acf246bb05b9ba5f82e0adbd0ad383 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I tried looking for plug ins in my IDE (Intellij) but the recommended one on google does not exist.

What plug in can I use that will work?
Is there an alternative plug in that I can use?

I tried to use older versions of the plug in but that also failed also producing a checksum validation error. I was hoping to find a compatible version. I used the first stable version just after the beta releases and that also failed, producing the same error. I also used version 20.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the grails version of my application does not "accomodate" the big query plug-ins. I will have to upgrade my grails from 2.5.6 to a higher version